# How to display this span tag correctly in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following the ruby code

```
content_tag(:li, render_menu_node(node, content_tag(:span, caption), url, selected))
```

displays the span tag like this:

```
<li><a href="" class="selected">&lt;span&gt;Foo&lt;/span&gt;</a></li>
```

How can I make it display like this?

```
<li><a href="" class="selected"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
```

Comment: You can try wrapping the call to content_tag(:span, caption) with h(content_tag(:span, caption)).

Comment: I tried it, but it still does the same thing. It adds &amp; like this: <li><a href="" class="selected">&amp;lt;span&amp;gt;Foo&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;</a></li>

Comment: what does `render_menu_node` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is Rails 3, then use either

```
content_tag(:li, raw(render_menu_node(node, content_tag(:span, caption), url, selected)))
```

or

```
content_tag(:li, render_menu_node(node, content_tag(:span, caption), url, selected).html_safe)
```

or even better modify `render_menu_node` to return `html_safe` string. Be sure to `h` all user input inside that method however.

You may need to use one of these techniques inside your method. Also make sure you are *not* wrapping what you get from `content_tag(:span, caption)` in a `h` method call. Post your code for more details.

If this is not Rails 3, you'll need to post the source of that method.